# Drupal 7 - Vote up/down module configuration

Tags: drupal, module, vote

I'm trying to solve a problem with my Drupal website. I installed and configured **Vote Up/Down** module and now I see, that only me as registred user can vote. Is there any way to let also  anonymous user vote?

Thanks for replies!
FM

Answer (score 0):

Did you allowed the usage of the Vote Up/Down widget for *Anonymous* users under People/Permissions?

The module(s) makes use of the *hook_perm* hook ...

```
function vud_node_perm() {
    return array('view vote up/down count on nodes', 'use vote up/down on nodes', 'administer vote up/down on nodes', 'see vote up/down node stats');
}
```

Comment: FYI: drupal 7 is not using hook_perm but instead it is hook_permission()!